# Problems with Request.QueryString. Reads cache instead of URL

Tags: c#, query-string, episerver

I'm trying to retrieve the value of myID from my URL.
I'm testing this using  <%=Request.QueryString["hotelid"] %>.

It only works the first time the page is loaded either in a new browser, or if my project has been rebuild.

My URL string is typical: **http://my/path/to/site/?hotelid=2**.

If I try <%=Request.QueryString %>, I'm also getting other values as well. Values I do not see inthe URL string.

What am I missing here?

**Update:**
Using <%=Request.RawUrl%>, I get the following results:
/Util/NotFound.aspx?404;http://localhost/en/Tjenester/Hotellguiden-2/Hotel-informasjon/?hotelid=3

I have NO idea what the **/Util/NotFound.aspx?404** is or where it comes from.

My URL looks like this:
http://localhost/en/Tjenester/Hotellguiden-2/Hotel-informasjon/?hotelid=2

**Update 2:**
I'm currently investigating if it is EPiServer CMS that is using some kind of caching.

**Update 3:**
I have solved it. EPiServer is using EPnCachePolicyTimeout which isset to 1 hour. Setting this to 0 (zero) solved my problem.

Sometimes is really helps just writing aboutthe problem here, talking "aloud" about it and voila :)

Comment: What value do you get for the querystring?

Comment: Using <%=Request.RawUrl%>, I get /Util/NotFound.aspx?404;http://localhost/en/Tjenester/Hotellguiden-2/Hotel-informasjon/?hotelid=3

Comment: Can you see the page in browser by giving the same URL?

Answer (score 3):

You need to [turn off caching](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Per/Archive/2008/10/Http-Caching-strategies-Pages/) or add your parameter names to the config attribute httpCacheVaryByParams or [overwrite the custom caching key method](http://labs.episerver.com/en/Blogs/Fredrik-Karlsson/Dates/2008/9/Implement-your-own-httpCacheVaryByCustom-method/) and make it diff on every querystring parameter.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the links. Not sure I like the approach of having to add variable names to the web.config as I code along!

Comment: For EPiServer 5 R2 and later I always use this approach:

In web.config:

httpCacheExpiration="0:1:0"
httpCacheability="Public"
httpCacheVaryByCustom="jk"
httpCacheVaryByParams="needs-a-value-but-not-used"


In Global:

public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string
custom)
{
  return context.Request.RawUrl;
}

Comment: That way there's no need to specify each param name.